# how can I import the documentation to the new project that reference the dll?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, documentation

hi
I am working with Library called Lucene.net.
I dowloaded the Visual studio 2010 "*.sln" project for this library using SVN

and the output of this "*.sln" project is a DLL
and to use this library I just add a reference to the dll in the new project that i want to use this project in it
my problem is that I can't see the documentation for the classes and the function of this library in the project that imported the dll While I can see the documentation for the classes and the functions in the main project that create this DLL
by the way:
(there is an html pages included with main project also contains the documentation that need to import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the xml file with the documentation

Comment: 1-which xml file?  2-from where should I bring this xml file?  3-and to where should I copy it?